# What's the equivalent of eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters for OpenJPA (Kodo)?

Tags: eclipselink, openjpa

When I use eclipselink (or toplink) , I can set the "eclipselink.jdbc.bind-parameters" hint to query, but it not works in OpenJpa( or Kodo), what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that OpenJPA has an equivalent parameter. If I understand the eclipselink documentation correctly, OpenJPA always parameterizes.